# Problem when trying to get all messages from personal dialog (Telethon)

Tags: python, telethon

I`m trying to get all messages from my personal dialog (only 1) with Telethon, but it doesn`t return that. I tried to put special parameter: 'name' of the dialog, but it doesn`t run. I`m only started to learn Python and can`t understand why code doesn`t work.

```
`with TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash) as client:
all_chats = client(functions.messages.GetAllChatsRequest(except_ids = []))
for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
    dialogs = client.get_dialogs()
    first = dialogs[1]
    print(first)
    break`
```

dialogs[1] - in my order of dialogs this is the place of the necessary dialog .

I get this:

Dialog(name='', date=datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 24, 12, 50, 9, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), draft=<telethon.tl.custom.draft........

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. My recommendation is that you start learning Python with simpler tutorials, specially if it's your first programming language. After you're a bit more confident, following Telethon's documentation in order should be relatively straightforward.

Comment: @Lonami thank you very much. Yes, it`s my first programming language. I solved my problem )

Answer (score 1):

For all the users interested in solving such problem, try:

```
chat = '@name'
api_id = ...
api_hash = ...

from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

client = TelegramClient('session_id', api_id, api_hash)

with client:
    # 30 is the limit on how many messages to fetch. Remove or change for more.
    for msg in client.iter_messages(chat, 30):
        print(msg.sender.first_name, ':', msg.text)
```

This works!